# Can't register DVC with Citrix

Tags: citrix, virtual-channel

I'm writing a DVC plugin. The plugin works as expected with RDP. However when accessing with Citrix, nothing happens.

According to the Citrix docs, registration proceeds as per the Microsoft docs for DVCs, which I've followed (backed up by successful tests with RDP). I used the second method originally but changed to the third after seeing [this](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/325526-dynamic-virtual-channel-not-fully-supported/?csrfKey=) saying that only the third is supported. This still works with RDP but again, doesn't work with Citrix.

I've looked into messing with the Citrix modules registry- there's a bunch of DVCAdapter stuff there that makes it look suspiciously like you're supposed to register DVCs additionally with Citrix, but after I added the entries comparable with the existing ones, nothing happened. The docs say that there is additional registration possible if you don't register it normally as Microsoft say (which I did) but don't say how to do it.

I've looked for configuration in Citrix since it seems they have configuration for everything; however when I've looked at the Policies, there seems to be nothing about virtual channels at all, let alone DVCs specifically.

I installed the Lync VDI plugin which allegedly uses a DVC to communicate over Citrix. However I've been unable to discern any actual effect on my registry from this installation so no inspiration there.

How can I register my DVC with Citrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my attempt to futz with the registry was the problem. When I undid my messing with the Citrix registry, then using the COM class registration method worked as expected.

Comment: Does your Citrix plugin work with both Xenapp and Xendesktop? I'm trying to wrestle with the same DVC registration issues, and though my plugin works fine in RDP and XenApp, the only method called by Citrix on XenDesktop is IWTSVirtualChannelManager::Initialize.

Calling pChannelMgr->CreateListener("FOOBAR", 0, cb, &ptrListener) is successful, but OnNewChannelConnection never gets called.

Comment: @Iwa I'm afraid that our customer only uses XenApp. However if any methods are invoked in your DLL then it will not be a DVC registration problem. It seems like the most logical reason for failure is that the remote end does not connect successfully, possibly due to some security requirement or other configuration setting unique to XenDesktop. I'm afraid I can't really help you with that.

Comment: I am connecting from the same client to an RDP server, XenApp server, and a XenDesktop server. I ran the exact same test program on each of these desktops, and it works correctly in RDP and XenApp, but doesn’t work in XenDesktop. Ugh. Thanks for your help anyway, I really appreciate it!